# How to calculate Var(x)?

Tags: variance

How do I calculate Var(x) if I know that $X | Y = y \sim N(y,1)$ and the PDF of Y is given by

$$
f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
3y^2 \ \ \ \text{for} \ 0 < y < 1 \\
0     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{othwerwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I thought about using the law of total variance:

$$
Var(x) = E[Var(X|Y)] + Var(E[X|Y]) = E[1] + Var(Y)
$$
Is this correct so far? And how do I calculate $E[1]$?

Comment: Is $E[1] = 1?$ And then $Var(y)$ I know how to calculate

Comment: you should write large $Var(X)$  instead of $Var(x)$ here and there (also in the title).

Answer (score 1):

The approach looks find to me. As you observed:

$E[X|Y]=Y$ and $Var(X|Y)=1$

Using the low of total variance than you correctly deduced:

$Var(X)=E[1]+Var(Y)$

Clearly:

$E[1]=1$, because the expectation value of a constant is the constant itself.

$Var(Y)$ can be computated as $E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2$, where:

$E[Y]=\int_0^1 3y^2y dy=3/4$

$E[Y^2]=\int_0^1 3y^2y^2 dy=3/5$